# NGINX 414 Error, after large_client in config gets 400 Error

Tags: http, url, nginx, bad-request

i have a weired problem with my nginx. I am getting the 414 URL Too Long. For that i add those 2 lines to the nginx.conf:

```
client_header_buffer_size 2k;
large_client_header_buffers 8 12k;
```

But as soon as i do "nginx restart" the error changes to "400 Bad request Your browser sent an invalid request." - without any additional information?

```
https://XXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXX?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22or%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002695%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003743%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003417%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002696%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000167%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005565%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001904%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003602%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003601%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001900%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005071%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005461%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003014%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003407%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000924%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002039%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002561%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003946%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002562%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003757%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003540%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003808%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005063%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003614%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002564%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002040%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003207%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003006%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001682%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003007%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003919%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003433%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003432%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001531%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003436%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002573%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003817%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003622%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002670%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003625%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003623%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003823%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004092%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003230%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001676%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003334%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000675%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003330%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003235%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001670%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000947%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003037%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002057%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005556%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003422%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000960%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003423%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000963%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002583%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002686%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001521%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001914%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002682%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005554%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003830%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003329%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002913%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000959%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005147%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001518%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000958%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001748%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001749%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000972%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003457%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000895%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000971%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003985%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001751%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001750%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000965%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000698%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000699%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002074%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003843%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003841%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001939%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004089%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001937%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004085%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004979%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005029%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000981%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000980%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001087%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003996%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001741%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004451%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001743%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005431%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003040%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003855%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000395%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000390%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002086%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002088%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000772%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003574%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001824%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000385%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000387%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000389%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001075%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004304%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004300%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003866%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001632%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003568%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001420%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000170%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000781%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000788%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000175%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001618%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003462%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000786%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001566%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000179%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001568%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004473%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002449%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003978%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001766%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001763%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002442%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005319%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004816%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000779%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001965%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000371%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003888%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001167%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003097%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000462%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001027%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003168%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002845%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001025%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003369%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000865%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002613%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001879%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002839%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003361%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003360%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000761%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001032%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003896%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003176%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002731%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002218%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002217%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001172%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001170%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000355%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001892%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004140%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002622%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002729%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001378%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001582%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001607%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002205%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002866%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002108%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002107%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002000%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004853%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004965%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003389%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003489%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000743%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003197%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000728%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001052%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000723%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001059%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002853%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000471%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005208%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002846%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003497%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002990%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004021%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002502%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002709%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002889%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002507%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002786%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004274%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003513%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000722%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003644%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000617%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003786%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003135%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000802%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002252%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002878%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000703%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004389%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000704%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002777%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000701%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002967%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003505%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002973%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003503%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003795%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000833%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002148%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003103%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280004397%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001006%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002626%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002958%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005254%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002528%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003101%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002768%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280001000%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002766%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005388%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000700%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002535%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002963%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002636%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002635%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003768%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002633%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000841%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000910%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002637%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003157%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280000433%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002751%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002393%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002391%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003155%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280005399%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003152%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002235%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002132%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003677%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002951%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280003675%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002953%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2280002548%22%7D%5D%7D%7D&access_token=XXXXXX
```

Do you have any idea? I tried to log it, but i don't see any information for the 400 error.

The requested is passed by proxy to one of our servers:

```
upstream api_admin_prod_server {
server XXXXXXX:5500;
}

location /XXXXXX {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
rewrite ^/services(.*)$ /api/$1 break;
proxy_pass http://api_admin_prod_server;
}
```